# making service available in ngRoute

Tags: angularjs

This code is from the angularjs TodoMVC. You can see `resolve` object of the routeConfig that it fetches the todos from localStorage (if localStorage is used). The localStorage code is created in an service in another file [todoStorage.js](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/angularjs/js/services). My question is, how is that service (or how is that code in general) available in this config for the fetch of the todo records?  Don't I have to make available the service somehow for the code below to use it?

```
angular.module('todomvc', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        'use strict';

        var routeConfig = {
            controller: 'TodoCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'todomvc-index.html',
            resolve: {
                store: function (todoStorage) {
                    // Get the correct module (API or localStorage).
                    return todoStorage.then(function (module) {
                        module.get(); // Fetch the todo records in the background.
                        return module;
                    });
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: you can only access store provider inside TodoCtrl by injecting `store` dependancy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`resolve` property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when) is a hash/dictionary of key value pairs.

The key is the eventual name of the value that will be available for injection. The value *can be an injectible function* that Angular will automatically pass dependencies into.

So when you see this code:

```
store: function (todoStorage) { ... }
```

Angular will automatically infer the `'todoStorage'` service from the parameter name and then inject it automatically. And of course it supports array notation as well:

```
store: ['todoStorage', function (todoStorage) { ... }]
```

In Angular pretty much anything can be [dependency injected](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Comment: inject it automatically after it compiles that app and sees that it exists in another file?

Comment: You register services and factories using the `.service()` or `.factory()` methods respectively. If you look at the `todoStorage` file you will notice this line of code: `angular.module('todomvc').factory('todoStorage',...)` That will register the service with Angular as the name `'todoStorage'`. Angular can then inject that service anywhere it is requested.